# Is the documentation from Embarcadero wrong for EncodeDateTime?

Tags: delphi

The documentation for [`System.DateUtils.EncodeDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/e/index.php?title=System.DateUtils.EncodeDateTime&oldid=624512) says:

> Valid hour values are 0 through 24. (If the specified hour is 24, the
>   minute, second, and millisecond values should all be 0, and the
>   resulting TDateTime value represents midnight at the end of the
>   specified day and the beginning of the next day).

If I try to do `EncodeDateTime(2008,1,1,24,0,0,0);` I receive an exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In reality, `0:00:00` represents midnight, and there's no such thing as `24:00:00`, so yes, the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @Jerry although the docs do say "at the end of the specified day" so what is documented could reasonably be implemented

Comment: @All, OT, meta question: shall we now (after the documentation has been fixed) close this question with the reason _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced"_?

Comment: @Victoria: i guess the offline documentation of Delphi is not yet corrected and will never corrected for version <= tokyo, only the online documentation have been corrected

Comment: @loki, good point. You're right there! But it's been more or less philosophical  question what to do in this case. Future visitor may get confused when they visit the documentation that you've linked.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but you can still link to older versions.

Comment: @Uwe, it's great that you've fixed that! I've linked the old version in the question though :) Just to not confuse future visitors.

Comment: @JerryDodge There's no time like 24:00:00 but occasionally, there's 23:59:60 :-) (search for "Leap Second") :-). I guess that Delphi (and other languages) don't support this :-)

Comment: @HeartWare, probably because there is no algorithm do calculate those.

Comment: @UweRaabe Just like there's no (definitive) algorithm to calculate the change date for DST switchover dates :-) - they are different depending on country/state and have even changed for the same country/state over time, even to the point that some places have changed the actual _having_ a DST or not over time :-). The only way is to maintain a list of the times that these things happen/change linked to geographical coordinates if that kind of accuracy is required :-).

Comment: @HeartWare, something like this? https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb

Comment: @UweRaabe Yes (although I can't vouch for the accuracy one way or the other - don't know enough about the changes all over the world). This should take care of the DST problem. The Leap Second problem is rather simple, as there are quite few of them - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Insertion_of_leap_seconds for a list of all leap seconds so far...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a defect in the documentation. The implementation of `TryEncodeTime`, which is what does the actual work, goes like this:

```
function TryEncodeTime(Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word; out Time: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  TS: TTimeStamp;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Hour < HoursPerDay) and (Min < MinsPerHour) and (Sec < SecsPerMin) 
    and (MSec < MSecsPerSec) then
  begin
    ....
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Since `HoursPerDay` is `24`, it is clear that the implementation does not agree with the documentation.

This isn't even behaviour that has changed over time. The `TryEncodeTime` method has always behaved this way. For instance, the analogous function from Delphi 5 looks like this:

```
function DoEncodeTime(Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word; var Time: TDateTime): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Hour < 24) and (Min < 60) and (Sec < 60) and (MSec < 1000) then
  begin
    Time := (Hour * 3600000 + Min * 60000 + Sec * 1000 + MSec) / MSecsPerDay;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Documentation is fixed now.